# Google Tag Manager Preview Mode for Mobile

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, preview

I just set up Google Tag Manager in my project and would like to test iOS/Android using the Preview Mode that's available for browser. Starting with Android I followed the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v3/#preview-publish) and was able to use the link successfully but I don't see any kind of Preview Mode. Where are the log messages that I would normally see if I used it on browser and how do I get to them? Thanks!

Comment: You can't see a debugger panel like in web pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preview mode in mobile doesn't work as similar in web.

You need to verify your changes from Logcat/Android Monitor or Xcode Console for which you have enable verbose logging.

Instructions to open container and see verbose logs;

1. Setup Google Tag Manager for app
2. Generate a preview url
3. Run your app
4. Open the preview url in emulator or device browser
5. Browser will redirect you to your app and open it
6. Check your Logcat/Android Monitor or Xcode Console for GoogleTagManager verbose logs

Comment: Awesome, I was missing the verbose logging part

Comment: What do you mean by enabling verbose logging in Xcode, where do we do this from ?